# Tail recursion optimization works with "\n" but not '\n' in std::cout

Tags: c++, tail-recursion

If the following code is optimized with the `-O3` flag, the tail recursion allows for the program to continue running without overflowing the call stack

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void rec (int n)
{
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    rec(n-1);
}

int main ()
{
    rec (10);
    return 0;
}
```

However, changing `"\n"` to `'\n'` and compiling with `-O3` results in stack overflow. It is unclear to me why this is the case. Perhaps it's just a bug and not an intended difference. Does anyone know why a character somehow disrupts the ability to optimize tail recursion in this case? (Compiled using **g++ (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)** or **Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)**) If compiled using **g++-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0**, both versions optimize as expected.

Comment: if the g++-10 could optimize it there is no reason in c++ why you can't optimize both cases. I think it is just the implementations of the optimalizers have become better.

Comment: gcc-10 optimises better than gcc-8. Looks like a move in the intended direction to me.

Comment: Note that c and c++ (unfortunately) don't guarantee tail call elimination. You can't rely on this anyway.

Comment: Do you really want infinite loop? (not infinite, as int overflow is UB as your program)

Comment: It isn't that I _want_ an infinite loop. This is just a constructive example of what I encountered. Int overflow does/will not apply to anything here; the values will print ad infinitum, wrapping around into the non-negatives.

Comment: Pedantically, it is UB, and wrapping around is not guaranteed. Removing the UB of the equation would be better, I expect that `if (n == 0) return;` and `rec(10'000)` should expose the same issue.